# I cannot import one of my node modules while the other ones work

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules

My Typescript folder structure looks like this

```
src
|aws folder
|    |__s3-controller.ts
|events-service folder
|    |__events-service-request.ts
|__index.ts
```

My index.ts has the following exports defined:

```
export * from './aws/s3-controller.js';
export * from './aws/sns-controller.js';
export * from './events-service/events-service-request.js';
```

the `events-service-request.ts` has the following

```
import axios from 'axios';

/**
 *
 */
export default class EventsService {
  baseUrl: string;

  constructor(baseUrl: string) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  async sendRequest(body: {}): Promise<void> {
    axios.post(
      `${this.baseUrl}/twirp/events.domain.Domain/FireDomainEvent`,
      body,
    );
  }
}
```

my package.json has the following:

```
"exports": {
    ".": "./dist/esm/actions/index.js",
    "./utils": "./dist/esm/utils/index.js"
  },
```

I am trying to import the functions from my `events-service-request.js` into my plain node project using `import EventsService from 'qa-data-tool/utils';` and I keep on getting the following error message:

```
import EventsService from 'qa-data-tool/utils';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'qa-data-tool/utils' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

but for some reason I can export the modules from my `aws` folder correctly.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. I've double checked and think everything is set up correctly but I'm pretty sure I'm missing some minuscule thats eluding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A star export does not re-export the default export of a module, otherwise you'd have three `default`s compete against each other.

You should use

- either a named export

  ```
  export class EventsService {
    …
  }
  ```

  with a start re-export

  ```
  export * from './events-service/events-service-request.js';
  ```
- or a default export

  ```
  export default class EventsService {
    …
  }
  ```

  with an aliasing re-export

  ```
  export { default as EventsService } from './events-service/events-service-request.js';
  ```